# How to sort sql server table on open in ssms

Tags: sql

How would I sort a table in SQL Server when it is opened? My table has an autonumber field that increments sequentially and it is the primary key field also.

I'd like to have another numeric field sorted smallest to largest and then have the autonumber field to use the auto field number relying on the other numeric field.

[image: showing table sorting]

The image shows how the table is currently sorted. I'd like to have the table sorted when it opens from ssms by the second column.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 0):

the sort depends on cluster index, by default any primary key will create a clustered index on that column so the table will be sorted based on it.

if you want to sort the table based on another column you need to drop your cluster index and create it on the second column.

Comment: No, that's totally incorrect and is giving the OP the wrong information. SQLServer is not guaranteed to return data in any particular order unless you explicitely request it, regardless of clustered indexes.

Comment: you can check :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That deals with physicial implementation, logically a table is an unordered set and ordering is not guaranteed if not specified, that's a fact of all RDBMS systems.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I sort a table in SQL Server when it is opened?

You cannot.  SQL tables represent *unordered* (multi)sets.  They have no inherent ordering.  To get data in order, you need an explicit `order by` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
order by col2 asc;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(col2)`.

If you declared the second column as a descending clustered index, then *in practice* you would probably see smaller values first.  However, even with a clustered index, SQL Server does not guarantee that a `SELECT` with no `ORDER BY` will return the rows in any order.  Period.  There is no guarantee.